# Unable to set Width propery on Form

Tags: html, css, forms, width

It seems i cant set the width property of my Email input form (Via picture). For some reason `width:100%;` on the parent or child element does not work as intended. I need the form input to be as wide as all the other elements on my personal page

**Here you can see the code:**
https://codepen.io/wodosharlatan/pen/ExpbVwg?editors=1100

Any help is appreciated and thanks for your time

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's due to your `display: grid;` setting on the parent. This means the form will have the same width as the widest element in its column. In this case the contact__information div.

The solution is to add the following to your css:

```
.contact__form {
   grid-column:  span 2;
}
```

This will stretch your form over the width of the two columns.